# set input value to there corresponding tags

Tags: javascript, dom

I wish to set each input value to it's corresponding tags without using the id attributes.

Here is what i have. This doesn't work.

This sets every tag the value of "last name".

```js
var form = document.forms['form'];
var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
var p = document.querySelectorAll('#display .editable');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  inputs.forEach(function(input){
    for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
      p[i].innerHTML = input.value;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="first name">
      <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="middle name">
      <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="last name">
      <button>SHOW</button>
    </form>

    <div id="display">
      <p class="editable"><!--first name--></p>
      <p class="editable"><!--middle name--></p>
      <p class="editable"><!--last name--></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for multiple loops. Do it with a single one and use the index for both.

```js
var form = document.forms['form'];
var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
var p = document.querySelectorAll('#display .editable');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    p[i].innerHTML = inputs[i].value;
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="first name">
  <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="middle name">
  <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="last name">
  <button>SHOW</button>
</form>

<div id="display">
  <p class="editable">
    <!--first name-->
  </p>
  <p class="editable">
    <!--middle name-->
  </p>
  <p class="editable">
    <!--last name-->
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var form = document.forms['form'];
var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
var p = document.querySelectorAll('#display .editable');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  inputs.forEach(function(input,i){
      p[i].innerHTML = input.value;

  });
});
```

```html
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="first name">
      <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="middle name">
      <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="last name">
      <button>SHOW</button>
    </form>

    <div id="display">
      <p class="editable"><!--first name--></p>
      <p class="editable"><!--middle name--></p>
      <p class="editable"><!--last name--></p>
    </div>
```